# how to add a splitview controller in a tabbar 

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i m having a problem where there is a need to add a split view controller in my tabbar applicaion .i need to add a split view controller in my second tabbar item .is der any possibility to add a splitivew controller in my second tabbar .

Comment: Maybe you could clearify your question? (perhaps make a pic of the situation you would like to see?)

If you want 2 UIViewControllers on 1 screen with a shared tabbar. Why not use a mainVC with those 2 viewControllers on them. But ye could use some more info here.

Comment: i ve got 4 tabbar item..in my second tabbar item i need to add a split view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a splitViewController programmatically you use something like this.

```
UISplitViewController *c = [[[UISplitViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
c.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myVC1, myVC2, nil];
```

And to hide those navigationbars of those myVC1 and myVC2 you will have to use

```
myVC1.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
myVC2.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

Hope it helps ;)